# scalar curvature on one - dimensional Riemannian Manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

How can i express the scalar curvature for a one - dimensional Riemannian manifold (M, g) in terms of the metric g ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A one-dimensional Riemannian manifold does not have any intrinsic curvature at all. It is always locally isometric to a straight, "flat" line.

Formally, the Riemann curvature tensor has but a single component $R_{1111}$, but this element is required to be 0 due to (for example) the skew-symmetry of $R_{ijkl}$.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot that's what I suspected.

Comment: Can this local isometry always be promoted to a global isometry (of course if there is no topological obstruction) ?

Comment: @Lor: Good question. I _think_ every Riemannian metric on $\mathbb R$ is isometric to an open subset of $\mathbb R$, but I cannot rattle off a proof.

Comment: Yes, the isometry is given by a unit speed geodesic.

Comment: How can one compute the global curvature of a circle seen as a 1D manifold with a metric, without embedding it into $\mathbb{R}^2$?