# flat manifold, curvature and the circle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

A Riemannian manifold is said to be flat if the curvature is 0 everywhere. An example in dimension 1 is the circle. However, I cannot see how the curvature of the circle could be 0. See for instance:

[Curvature of a circle](https://planetmath.org/curvatureofacircle)

How could the curvature of a circle be 0?
How to show the [Riemannian curvature](https://planetmath.org/riemanncurvaturetensor) is 0?

Please help.

Comment: You are confusing two notions of curvature.  There is the geodesic curvature of a circle (which depends on its embedding in the plane) and the Riemannian curvature of the circle (which is intrinsic).

Comment: To add a bit of intuition onto the other responses: A sphere is *intrinsically* curved in the sense that you can't cut it in half, say, and "flatten it out" without distorting lengths, angles, or both.  That's more or less why any map of the Earth is a compromise.  A cylinder, on the other hand, can be cut and rolled out into a flat sheet, so it has no intrinsic curvature, in exactly the same way that you can cut a circle and roll it out to a line segment.

Comment: I no longer work on PDE (for many years). Answers received appeared to be way too late and so I could not credit the helpfulness
https://leannejdong.github.io/

Comment: A standard result is that the geodesic [curvature of a circle](https://planetmath.org/curvatureofacircle) is the reciprocal of its radius (plus or minus, depending on the direction of parametric embedding in the plane, so extrinsic). The [Riemann curvature tensor](https://planetmath.org/riemanncurvaturetensor) is defined intrinsically from the "distances" (metric) between points of a smooth manifold.  If you have no objection, I'll update the links in the body of your Question.

Comment: The topic of the curvature of a circle was implicitly discussed here under [scalar curvature on one-dimensional Riemannian manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99365/scalar-curvature-on-one-dimensional-riemannian-manifold).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you look at a circle, you are seeing its extrinsic curvature, which is also what your link is calculating. That is a property of how the circle is imbedded into another manifold, not a property of the circle as a manifold itself.

The curvature being referred to here is the intrinsic curvature, which is defined strictly in terms of the manifold itself, not any imbedding. 1-dimensional manifolds are incapable of supporting any curvature, so the circle is flat.

Comment: Many thanks. How to check circle can be regarded as a 1-dimensional manifold?

Comment: How to show the Riemannian curvature (i.e. the intrinsic curvature) is 0?

Comment: It is obviously one dimensional. $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ provides smooth 1-d maps. What more do you want? As for the curvature, look at the definition. It requires two idependent coordinates to have anything that isn't 0.

Comment: Your first sentence is clear to me. My second question is that, I wish to compute Riemannian curvature. But I have never learnt to do such thing before. Could you show me how the curvature of circle computed as 0? In what books contains preliminary like this?

Comment: If $D$ is the Levi-Civita connection, then the curvature tensor is given by: $$R_{XY}Z = D_{[X, Y]}Z - [D_X, D_Y]Z$$ Since the Lie bracket is an anticommutator ($[U, V] = - [V, U]$), it is 0 if both vectors, or both operators are the same, or even parallel. In a 1D manifold, all vectors are parallel (since there is only one direction for them to point), so the Lie brackets are always 0, and so is the curvature.

Comment: Thanks. I shall review Lie bracket, learn how to differentiate tensor field, then get to the riemann tensor.

Comment: forgot to say...what you said made sense

Comment: That's good to know. I was afraid I went too high-powered, but I wanted to give the gist of the reason without getting bogged down in details.

Comment: I forgot to ask a thing, the formula you gave for the curvature tensor above...is from which book? It looks different from what is written from my notes...

Comment: I looked it up (haven't looked at this in many years) in O'Neill's Semi-Riemannian Geometry. I can't recall where I first encountered it.

Comment: http://pentagono.uniandes.edu.co/~jarteaga/trabajo-diario/sub-riemannian/geometric-control-theory/references-add/COL-UNIA-0024062_01.pdf

Comment: Page 3 above link has a similar formula, but the sign is opposite. Could you reconcile why ?

Comment: @math101 - I'm afraid not. It appears to be a matter of convention (in both cases, they are defining the curvature tensor by this expression). I did double-check that I had copied O'Neill's version correctly. My own preference would be for the version that gives a positive scalar curvature to the sphere, but that would take some effort to figure out.